# Matching & conditional exploding in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

I'm facing a difficult problem that needs to be matched before exploding.

My problem is best described by data. It looks like below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [
        [0.05, 0.055, 0.055, 0.06, 0.065, 0.07, 0.075, 0.075, 0.085, 0.09, 1.32],
        [0.4, 0.06, 0.06, 0.13, 0.135, 0.145, 0.155, 0.17] , 
        [3.81, 0.3, 0.4, 0.425, 0.445, 0.48, 0.51, 0.54, 0.58, 0.62, 0.66, 0.66, 0.705, 0.53, 0.57, 0.61], 
        [7.395, 0.075, 0.085, 0.09, 0.095, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14],
        [0.105, 0.11, 0.12, 0.125, 0.135, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.205, 2.21]
    ], 
    'B' : [
        [0.680, 1.320],
        [0.520, 0.130, 0.135, 0.145, 0.155, 0.170],
        [8.035, 3.810],
        [0.945, 7.395],
        [1.790, 2.210]
    ],
    'C' : [
        ['08/01/91', '08/01/10'],
        ['09/01/92', '09/01/93', '09/01/94', '09/01/95', '09/01/96', '09/01/10'],
        ['11/01/91', '11/01/10'],
        ['09/01/93', '09/01/21'],
        ['12/01/92', '12/01/10']
    ]
})
```

```
df

A   B   C
0   [0.05, 0.055, 0.055, 0.06, 0.065, 0.07, 0.075, 0.075, 0.085, 0.09, 1.32]    [0.68, 1.32]    [08/01/91, 08/01/10]
1   [0.4, 0.06, 0.06, 0.13, 0.135, 0.145, 0.155, 0.17]  [0.52, 0.13, 0.135, 0.145, 0.155, 0.17] [09/01/92, 09/01/93, 09/01/94, 09/01/95, 09/01/96, 09/01/10]
2   [3.81, 0.3, 0.4, 0.425, 0.445, 0.48, 0.51, 0.54, 0.58, 0.62, 0.66, 0.66, 0.705, 0.53, 0.57, 0.61]   [8.035, 3.81]   [11/01/91, 11/01/10]
3   [7.395, 0.075, 0.085, 0.09, 0.095, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14] [0.945, 7.395]  [09/01/93, 09/01/21]
4   [0.105, 0.11, 0.12, 0.125, 0.135, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.205, 2.21]  [1.79, 2.21]    [12/01/92, 12/01/10]
```

It is guaranteed that the sum of elements of list in A is equal to sum of elements of list in B. Usually they are ordered, but there are cases where it is reverted.

For example cases like row 0, the first 10 elements sums up to 0.68, and 1.32 is matched in order.

However, row 2 is the other way around, as 3.81 matches the last element of B. B & C columns are from the same dataset, so they should be filpped over to match the order of A.

My desired output will be like below after matching & exploding:

```
      A         B        C
0   0.05      0.68    08/01/91 
0   0.055     0.68    08/01/91 
0   0.055     0.68    08/01/91 
0   0.06      0.68    08/01/91 
0   0.065     0.68    08/01/91 
0   0.07      0.68    08/01/91 
0   0.075     0.68    08/01/91 
0   0.085     0.68    08/01/91 
0   0.09      0.68    08/01/91 
0   1.32      1.32    08/01/10 
...
2   3.81      3.81    11/01/10
2   0.3       8.035   11/01/91         
2   0.4       8.035   11/01/91         
2   0.425     8.035   11/01/91           
2   0.445     8.035   11/01/91           
2   0.48      8.035   11/01/91          
2   0.51      8.035   11/01/91         
2   0.54      8.035   11/01/91          
2   0.58      8.035   11/01/91   
2   0.62      8.035   11/01/91   
2   0.66      8.035   11/01/91   
2   0.66      8.035   11/01/91   
2   0.705     8.035   11/01/91    
2   0.52      8.035   11/01/91   
2   0.57      8.035   11/01/91   
2   0.61      8.035   11/01/91
```

Any ideas and approaches are deeply appreciated.

I found I made error on above data, and I corrected it. B & C they always have exact number of elements in their list.

## Row 1 case: my desired output will be:

```
1   0.4       0.520   09/01/92                   
1   0.06      0.520   09/01/92               
1   0.06      0.520   09/01/92               
1   0.13      0.130   09/01/93               
1   0.135     0.135   09/01/94                
1   0.145     0.145   09/01/95                
1   0.155     0.155   09/01/96                
1   0.17      0.17    09/01/10
```

Comment: row 3 has about 5 entries in column B - [0.52, 0.13, 0.135, 0.145, 0.155, 0.17]. what's the rule for this wrt ur question?

Comment: @sammywemmy I corrected & updated the post, thanks for pointing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea in the following example is to create 'matched' lists of equal lengths in each column for each row in the data first, and to then 'transpose' (explode is not really correct here) those lists. This can also easily scale for more columns, let me now if you need any help on generalizing the function

```
def match_row(row):
    bc_mapping = {b: c for b, c in zip(row['B'], row['C'])}
    common_elements = set(row['A']).intersection(set(row['B']))
    sum_elements = set(row['B']).difference(common_elements)
    assert len(sum_elements) == 1  # Sanity check

    common_elements = sorted(common_elements)
    sum_element = list(sum_elements)[0]
    number_of_free_elements = len(row['A']) - len(common_elements)

    return pd.Series({
         'A': [element for element in row['A'] if element not in common_elements] + common_elements,
         'B': [sum_element] * number_of_free_elements + common_elements,
         'C': [bc_mapping[sum_element]] * number_of_free_elements + [bc_mapping[element] for element in common_elements]
    })


df = df. \
    apply(match_row, axis=1). \
    aggregate('sum'). \
    apply(pd.Series). \
    transpose()
```

**EDIT: Generalization to mutliple columns:**
The case of multiple columns is not so trivial, but the following should work:

```
df['D'] = df['B'].apply(lambda b: [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in b])

def match_row(row, variable_column, reference_column):
    fixed_columns = row.index.tolist()
    fixed_columns.remove(variable_column)
    fixed_columns.remove(reference_column)

    variable_elements = row[variable_column]
    reference_elements = row[reference_column]
    fixed_elements = row[fixed_columns].apply(pd.Series).T.values.tolist()

    fixed_elements_mapping = {
        reference: fixed_elements
        for reference, fixed_elements
        in zip(reference_elements, fixed_elements)
    }
    common_elements = set(variable_elements).intersection(set(reference_elements))
    sum_elements = set(reference_elements).difference(common_elements)
    assert len(sum_elements) == 1  # Sanity check

    common_elements = sorted(common_elements)
    sum_element = list(sum_elements)[0]
    number_of_free_elements = len(variable_elements) - len(common_elements)

    variable_and_reference_result = pd.Series({
        variable_column: [element for element in row['A'] if element not in common_elements] + common_elements,
        reference_column: [sum_element] * number_of_free_elements + common_elements,
    })
    fixed_coluumns_result = pd.Series({
        column_name: [fixed_elements_mapping[sum_element][i]] * number_of_free_elements +
                     [fixed_elements_mapping[element][i] for element in common_elements]
        for i, column_name
        in enumerate(fixed_columns)
    })
    return pd.concat([variable_and_reference_result, fixed_coluumns_result])


df = df. \
    apply(lambda row: match_row(row, 'A', 'B'), axis=1). \
    aggregate('sum'). \
    apply(pd.Series). \
    transpose()
```

Comment: What should I do when I have another columns, say 'D', 'E' which should behave same way as column 'C'? I think I should work on ```bc_mapping``` part but not quite sure how.

Comment: @MatthewSon I edited my answer with an example (only with column 'D" but it should generalize for any number of columns

Answer (score 1):

I feel the proper, less nasty way to achieve your goal is to step out of Pandas and into Python. Here goes the code with comments on the sides. Lemme know if it works on your end, as expected. It worked fine on my end :

```
M = df.to_dict('records') #return dataframe as a dictionary
```

This is where the computation occurs:

```
from operator import itemgetter


coll=[]

for (i,j) in enumerate(M):

    #get value(s) that are in both  lists
    yes = set(M[i]['A'])&set(M[i]['B'])

    #lump B and C, we need the date included   
    merge = list(zip(M[i]['B'],M[i]['C'])) 

    #give values that are in the yes set
    yes_filter = [r for r in merge if r[0] in yes] 

    #give values that are not in the yes set
    no_filter = [r for r in merge if r[0] not in yes] 

    #create box to house items in 'A' column that are not in the 'yes' set 
    #the indexing will help in sorting the values before
    #putting them back into the dataframe
    no_content = [(p,j) for (j,p) in enumerate(M[i]['A']) if p not in yes] 

    #reverse of line above
    yes_content = [(p,j) for (j,p) in enumerate(M[i]['A']) if p in yes] 

    #lump no content and no_filter
    nawano = [(q,s,*f) for q,s,f in [(*q,*no_filter) for q in no_content]] 

    #lump yes content and yes filter
    nawayes = [(*p,*q) for p,q in zip(yes_content,yes_filter)] 

    nawano.extend(nawayes)

    #we use the index to sort the list 
    nawano = sorted(nawano,  key=itemgetter(1)) 

    coll.extend(nawano)
```

Now, we can return to Pandas :

```
#create dataframe
outcome = pd.DataFrame(coll, columns = ['A','temp','B','C']).drop('temp',axis=1) 

outcome.head()

      A      B         C
0   0.050   0.68    08/01/91
1   0.055   0.68    08/01/91
2   0.055   0.68    08/01/91
3   0.060   0.68    08/01/91
4   0.065   0.68    08/01/91
```

I'm pretty sure this can be optimized. If u find a better solution, pls let me know. I'd love to learn as well. Cheers.

Comment: Could there be a way to define this task in a function, so that it may be called in pandas apply? It is because I have other many columns to keep (say column D) from exploding so that I may use similar to this form : ```df.set_index('D').apply(lambda x : My_explode_function(x))```